# Macbook/MacOS: Make command button move one word instead of going all the way to the right and left, like windows

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard, macbook

1. How do I make "command" move one word instead of going all the way to the right and left, like windows.
   I know if I press option then I can move left and right one word at a time, but then I can't use command + a ( to select all) + command c/v/w (to copy, paste, close window) and other commands.

so basically I want to press command + right arrow or command + left arrow and go one word at a time.

also i want to do the same thing with command + d (so in windows in chrome it would be alt + d which would select the url)

Thank you!!

Comment: Why don't you just press alt/arrow instead?

Comment: it is messing up my muscle-memory a lot :) -- I use both laptops, windows and macbook. I am used to ma

Comment: The keys are in different places anyway. Mac is Ctrl/Alt/Cmd, Windows is Ctrl/Win/Alt. Moving global command structures is really not easy anyway & will mess up many other things.